# Flutter: how to hold both ID & Text in a Controller?

Tags: flutter, dart

I was wondering if there's any possibility to hold both ID & Text in a Controller like `TextEditingController` and be able to access both values anytime.

Lets say I have the following controller:

```
final TextEditingController customerController = new TextEditingController();
```

While showing the input to the user, I'd like to show the Text ("John Doe") but when saving into database I only need the ID (2192). I know that I can create a variable just to hold the ID, but I'd like to know if I can use the controller to hold both values.

I tried using `text` & `value` properties but with no success:

```
customerController.text = "2192";
customerController.value = TextEditingValue(text: "John Doe");

print(customerController.text); // Prints "John Doe"
print(customerController.value); // Prints "John Doe"
```

Comment: I suggest you to look into extension methods of dart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking through the documentation of [`TextEditingController`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TextEditingController-class.html) it is not possible to do this unless if you change the value to hold both the ID and the text value of the `TextEditingController`.

As the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TextEditingController-class.html) says:

```
text ↔ String
The current string the user is editing.

value ↔ TextEditingValue
The current value stored in this notifier.
```

Which means you can use `customerController.text` to display the text you want, but in the value you can store for example `2192_TheValueOfYourTextProperty` and then when storing in the database, split the value on the underscore.

Although I don't think you should use it that way. A separate variable or a class would be better to store things like this.

Comment: Hi, yeah, I thought about spliting but I was wondering if anything better would be available, like C# Winforms where you can use the `tag` property to store any value.

Comment: If you look in the documentation of TextEditingController. It is not possible to do something like that. Maybe look into ChangeNotifier, that allows you to store values upon changing a value (in for example a textfield). This does allow you to pass a class to the ChangeNotifier (with Provider package to make it easier). Which means you can make a class Customer with as many properties as you want, and then on the onChange() of your textfield you can update the values in that specific class.